rsyslog not working after logs are rotated till rsyslog is restarted
In rsyslog.conf I have
if $fromhost-ip == '192.168.5.1' then /var/log/fw_home.log
& stop

If I restart rsyslog everything is fine and there is output to the file. In /etc/logrotate.d/fw_home I have
/var/log/fw_home.log {
    su root adm
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    create 0640 syslog adm
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/systemctl reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}

If I then run sudo logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/fw_home then the file does get rotated however rsyslog does not write anything unless I restart rsyslog. If I try systemctl reload rsyslog I get
root@server2:~# systemctl reload rsyslog
Failed to reload rsyslog.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit rsyslog.service.
root@server2:~# 

Can I assume that the issue is that rysyslog does not see the file since I rotated it and in order for it to work instead of a reload I need to issue a restart? I would assume that a restart of a service should not be in order to simply rotate a log.

Does systemctl -p CanReload show rsyslog print CanReload=yes? Does systemctl -p ExecReload show rsyslog print ExecReload=kill -HUP $MAINPID (or something complicated that resolves to this)?
